# Question reg expo FileSystem.readAsStringAsync

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm pretty new to react native and need some help reg. the possiblity to read an image from a file (like an image). I'm using the expo filesystem library with the following code:

```
const uploadImages = (file) => {
   let data = null;
   try {
      data = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(file);
      console.log(data)
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
  }
```

The issue I have is that I get: 'await' is only allowed within async functions

How can I call this function to wait until the data is loaded into the data variable ?

Answer (score 0):

`FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(...)` returns `Promise`.
You can use `Promise` api like `.then()` and `.catch()`:

```
const uploadImages = (file) => {
   FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(file)
     .then(data => {
       // Do something with your data in this block
       console.log(data);
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log(err.message)
     })
}
```